# Taking part of JsonNode and updating it without modifying the main JsonNode using Java

Tags: java, json

I have main JsonNode,
`{{k1 : v1} = s1, {k2 : v2} = s2, {k3 : v3} = s3}`

Im taking one node key  `{k1 : v1}` separately and assigning it to another variable and updating it to {k1 : n1} without actually modifying the main JsonNode. But in the end if I see the main JsonNode  it got updated to `{{k1 : n1} = s1, {k2 : v2} = s2, {k3 : v3} = s3}`

How to take single node and update it without actually modifying the main node?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
JsonNode newJsonNode = originalJsonNode.get("k1").deepCopy();
```

You should then be able to edit the new node at will without it having an impact on your original node.